# What user agent does Chrome Mobile Beta have?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I don't own any Android device and right now nobody is online that I could ask: What's the user agent of the new Chrome Mobile Beta?

Could someone visit this site http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ with Chrome Mobile and copy it in here? I'm trying to match all mobile browsers with PHP and the user agent string and Chrome Mobile is missing! :)

// I know the user agent will be a little different for every device, so the question title is not exact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the useragent from chrome beta on my transformer prime

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-us; Transformer Prime TF201 Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) CrMo/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7

Answer (score 3):

Mine is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.2; en-us; Galaxy Nexus Build/ICL53F) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) CrMo/16.0.912.75 Mobile Safari/535.7

Comment: Thanks! :) I accepted the other answer, because it is older, but I also upvoted yours.